# Google Places API (nearby search) module in Excel VBA returns "#NAME?"

Tags: excel, vba, google-places-api

I am using the Google Places API Nearby Search from Excel VBA and am receiving the "#NAME?" response using this code when "MyAPIKey" is replaced with my API key and the latitude/longitude/radius are set as follows:

latitude: 45.5662453
longitude: 122.6628821
radius: 200

Are there any issues with the syntax?  I know there is at least one park within a 200-meter radius:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetNearbyPark(latitude As Double, longitude As Double, radius As Integer) As String
        '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'This function returns the park name and address for a given latitude and longitude and radius using the Google Places Nearby Search API.
'Radius is in meters
```

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
'Declaring the necessary variables.
Dim apiKey                   As String
Dim str                      As String
Dim xmlhttpRequest           As Object
Dim xmlDoc                   As Object
Dim xmlStatusNode            As Object
Dim xmlNearbyParkNameNode    As Object
Dim xmlNearbyParkAddressNode As Object
   
'Set your API key in this variable.
'Here is the ONLY place in the code where you have to put your API key.
apiKey = MyAPIKey

'Check that an API key has been provided.
If apiKey = vbNullString Or apiKey = "The API Key" Then
    GetNearbyPark = "Empty or invalid API Key"
    Exit Function
End If

'Generic error handling.
On Error GoTo errorHandler
        
'Create the request object and check if it was created successfully.
Set xmlhttpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
If xmlhttpRequest Is Nothing Then
    GetNearbyPark = "Cannot create the request object"
    Exit Function
End If
    
'Create the request based on Google Places API. Parameters (from Google page):
'- Longitude
'- Latitude
'- Radius

xmlhttpRequest.Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?" & "location=" & latitude & "," & longitude & "&radius=" & radius & "&type=park&key=" & apiKey & "&sensor=False"


'Send the request to the Google server.
xmlhttpRequest.send

'Create the DOM document object and check if it was created successfully.
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
If xmlDoc Is Nothing Then
    GetNearbyPark = "Cannot create the DOM document object"
    Exit Function
End If

'Read the XML results from the request.
xmlDoc.LoadXML xmlhttpRequest.responseText

'Get the value from the status node.
Set xmlStatusNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//status")

'Based on the status node result, proceed accordingly.
Select Case UCase(xmlStatusNode.Text)

    Case "OK"                       'The API request was successful.
                                    'At least one result was returned.
        
        'Get the park name node value of the first result.
        Set xmlNearbyParkNameNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//PlaceSearchResponse/result/name")
        
        'Return the park name as text
        GetNearbyPark = xmlNearbyParkNameNode.Text
    
    Case "ZERO_RESULTS"             'The geocode was successful but returned no results.
        GetNearbyPark = "No park exists within the radius of the defined coordinates"
        
    Case "OVER_DAILY_LIMIT"         'Indicates any of the following:
                                    '- The API key is missing or invalid.
                                    '- Billing has not been enabled on your account.
                                    '- A self-imposed usage cap has been exceeded.
                                    '- The provided method of payment is no longer valid
                                    '  (for example, a credit card has expired).
        GetNearbyPark = "Billing or payment problem"
        
    Case "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"         'The requestor has exceeded the quota limit.
        GetNearbyPark = "Quota limit exceeded"
        
    Case "REQUEST_DENIED"           'The API did not complete the request.
        GetNearbyPark = "Server denied the request"
        
    Case "INVALID_REQUEST"           'The API request is empty or is malformed.
        GetNearbyPark = "Request was empty or malformed"
    
    Case "UNKNOWN_ERROR"            'The request could not be processed due to a server error.
        GetNearbyPark = "Unknown error"
    
    Case Else   'Just in case...
        GetNearbyPark = "Error"
    
End Select
    
'Release the objects before exiting (or in case of error).
errorHandler:
  Set xmlStatusNode = Nothing
  Set xmlNearbyParkNameNode = Nothing
  Set xmlNearbyParkAddressNode = Nothing
  Set xmlDoc = Nothing
  Set xmlhttpRequest = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Please show the formula you use.

Comment: That error would suggest that you haven't enabled macros, or you put the code in the wrong place - it needs to be in a normal module (and one that does *not* have the same name as the function)

Comment: Thank you Rory.  There are no macros.  The code is in Modiule 1.  Is Module 1 the wrong location for the code?

Comment: I created a new Excel macro-enabled spreadsheet and dropped the code in the VBA module.  The code is now working so it must have been in the wrong place prevoiusly..  Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: I'll bet that the module containing your ´GetNearbyPark´ function was named ´GetNearbyPark´ as well... this will yield #NAME when you invoke it from Excel.